# Add a decimal year to a moment.js date

Tags: momentjs

How can I add a decimal/float value to a moment.js date object?

```js
moment('2017-09-20').add(1.234, 'years');
```

does only change the year and month, not the day. I was expecting that moment will calculate the correct date of `'2017-09-20'` plus one year plus the nearest day of the 0.234th of the year 2018. But instead it prints out `'2017-11-20'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [`moment.duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for `1.234` years and then `add` using [`moment().add(Duration);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/).

**EDIT**:

`1.234` years is equal to 1 year and `2.808` months as you can see using [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-iso-string/). The same duration is equal to `451` days. As the [`asDays()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/) states:

> `moment.duration().asDays()` gets the length of the duration in days.

So you can use `asDays()` output as input of `add(Number, String);`.

Here a live example:

```js
// Create moment duration for 1.234 years
var dur = moment.duration(1.234, 'years');
// 1.234 years is equal to 1 year and 2.808 months
console.log(dur.toISOString()); // P1Y2.808M
// 1.234 years is also equal to 451 days
console.log(dur.asDays()); // 451

// Add duration using moment().add(Duration);
var m1 = moment('2017-09-20').add(dur);
console.log(m1.format()); // 2018-12-20T00:00:00+01:00

// Add number of days
var m2 = moment('2017-09-20').add(dur.asDays(), 'd');
console.log(m2.format()); // 2018-12-15T00:00:00+01:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good idea, but the day does not change here either. Only the year and month. The day stays `20`, no matter if you add `1.2` or `1.25`.

Comment: @user2113177 I've updated my answer. The key is to understand what you expect to be the value of `1.234` years.

Comment: That's it. - Thanks a lot!